# Вывод количества дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть меню с подменю, нужно с помощью JS посчитать количество подпунктов и вывести это число возле названия пункта. То есть возле пункта О нас нужно вывести число его дочерних пунктов, в данном случаи 3
Код:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-item">Главная</li>
<li class="menu-item"><a href="#">О нас</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li class="menu1">О компании</li>
  <li class="menu2">Лицензии</li>
  <li class="menu3">Награды</li>
</ul></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Обновлено*

```js
(function(){

let menuItem = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
let num      = document.getElementsByClassName('num');
let count;
for(let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++){
  count = menuItem[i].getElementsByTagName('li').length;
  if( count != 0 ){
    num[i].innerHTML += ' (' + count  + ')';
  }
}

})();
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Главная<span class="num"></span></li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">О нас</a><span class="num"></span>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu1">О компании</li>
      <li class="menu2">Лицензии</li>
      <li class="menu3">Награды</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Не мог понять почему не работает, оказывается я ошибся в написании начального кода. Не могли бы вы подсказать что нужно изменить чтобы работало по этому коду (код исправил в вопросе)?

Comment: Решил сам. Спасибо!

Comment: Ой. *Чуть позже обновил ответ))

Answer (score 0):

Используйте JQuery:

```
var count = $(".sub-menu li").length;
```

Или:

```
var count = $(".sub-menu").children().length;
```